# How to change image name and put "-" in place of space, while uploading it.

Tags: php, file-upload, image-upload

I am using this code to upload images with PHP

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);



if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 
$target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
} 
?>
```

I want this: If I upload a image named "New York.jpg", the name gets changed to "New-York.jpg"

Comment: use php's `rename` function

Comment: How script will detect the space and place "-" instead of space?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` do rename the file already so just sanitize `$target_file` as you want... `str_replace` or `preg_replace` will work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code , here :

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

add :

```
$target_file = str_replace(' ', '-', $target_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

with this 2 lines,

```
$target_filename = str_replace(' ', '_', basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
$target_file = $target_dir . $target_filename;
```